# How to add Precall method in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have one requirement to fulfill.

Actually when ever user Login into my application , i will save the logged in user name in session attribute like .

```
session.setAttribute("LOGIN_USER", userName);
```

So that, if user tries to access my method links directly with out coming from Login page i can check in controller method whether this session has the specific attributive value as below and i can restrict user to access that page and redirect him to login page.

```
if(request.getSession(false).getAttribute("LOGIN_USER")==null)
 //redirect to login page
```

Now,my requirement is if i have 50 methods in controller i can't add this condition in each method.I think there is a way we can add some sort of filters or any method in controller class like ex @preExecuteMethod to first execute this method and proceed for the actual call if success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `HandlerInterceptor` for this.  See the docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) and [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors).

Comment: How can i use this for Annotation based controller?

Comment: @Rana: By reading the documentation I just linked to, then giving it a go.  If you have trouble making it work, ask another question showing us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Interceptor is the solution. It has methods preHandler which will be called before each request. You can hook into each HTTPServletRequest object and do the nnecessary stuff.

here is a sample code:

```
@Component
public class AuthCodeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        // set few parameters to handle ajax request from different host
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1000");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "private");

        String reqUri = request.getRequestURI();
        String serviceName = reqUri.substring(reqUri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                reqUri.length());
        if(request.getSession(false).getAttribute("LOGIN_USER")==null) {
            //redirect to login page
        }
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though it's constructed, `preHandle` never seems to be called, at least not when using `MockMvc`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an AOP @Before aspect giving the pointcut to  the methods in your handler class ? See the reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj) or you could create a normal filter via the [delegatingFilterProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) explained [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?20230-Howto-The-joy-that-is-DelegatingFilterProxy&highlight=filter%20interface) . I think overall @skaffman gives a better idea .